# Changing port of nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, apache-1.3

I want to run apache and nginx on same machine. I configured apache and running fine on port 80. 
Now I want to configure nginx on port 7007. I did changes in nginx.conf. Here is the nginx.conf file-

```
user nginx root;
worker_processes  3;
worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;


error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  65535;
    use epoll;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
        index index.php index.htm index.html;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    access_log off;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
   tcp_nodelay     on;
    server_tokens   off;
    gzip            on;
    gzip_static     on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    keepalive_timeout  80 15;
  #  limit_conn_zone   $binary_remote_addr  zone=addr:10m;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
#        limit_conn addr 20000;

        listen       7007;
        server_name  _;




            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location / {


        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;

        location = /404.html {
  }
        location /favicon.ico {
            empty_gif;
        }


        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {

        }

 location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 8m;
            fastcgi_send_timeout  8m;
        }

#        location ~ \.php$ {
#            root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
            #fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
#            fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php.sock;
#            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            #include        fastcgi_params;
#           fastcgi_send_timeout  8m;

#           fastcgi_connect_timeout 8m;
            #uwsgi_pass_request_body off;
#           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
 #       }

        location /status {
                stub_status on;
                access_log   off;
        #       allow ;
        #        allow 127.0.0.1;
        #        deny all;
        }

    }

}
```

When I start Nginx it shows Job failed. Here is the log.

```
Mar  7 15:55:12 localhost nginx[10973]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Mar  7 15:55:12 localhost nginx[10973]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Mar  7 15:55:12 localhost nginx[10975]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar  7 15:55:12 localhost nginx[10975]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar  7 15:55:13 localhost nginx[10975]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar  7 15:55:13 localhost nginx[10975]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar  7 15:55:14 localhost nginx[10975]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar  7 15:55:14 localhost nginx[10975]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Mar  7 15:55:14 localhost systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar  7 15:55:14 localhost systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
```

Why it still going for port 80 ?

Comment: Check `/etc/nginx/conf.d` to make sure there are no config files in there with conflicting directives.

Comment: yes there was a default.conf file in conf.d folder which was restricting. Now nginx has installed on 7007 port but new problem arises. Php fastcgi is not working. When I installed nginx on port 80 after removing apache, fastcgi works properly. do you have any idea why it is so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure that you have no config file using port 80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

2) Try to stop then start Nginx rather that restart it. Restart can be a problem with changing ports, sometimes.

Comment: you are right.. there was a default.conf file in conf.d folder which was restricting. Now nginx has installed on 7007 port but new problem arises. Php fastcgi is not working. When I installed nginx on port 80 after removing apache, fastcgi works properly. do you have any idea why it is so ?

Comment: Now I am no more able to run php on apache. Before nginx installation php was running well but after nginx installatino apache showing php code.

Comment: Are you sure PHP FPM is running on 127.0.0.1:9000 ? You should check PHP FPM config (default is `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf on Debian`).
The new default way to connect Nginx with PHP FPM is a UNIX socket. Try to set `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` instead of `fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;`

Comment: when I run this command..                                          netstat -tulpn | grep :9000 it shows                                       {tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3565/php-cgi      } it means phpcgi is running.

Comment: Ok. What errors do you get? Have checked the logs? (`/var/log/php5-fpm.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log`)
If my answer helped you, don't forget to upvote it ;-)

Comment: I removed php and reinstalled. Now everything is fine.